# JFace-Dialog: How to query user-input

Tags: java, dialog, widget, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using an org.eclipse.ui.forms.FormDialog-derived class to query users of my RCP-Application for input. This is a modal dialog which is closed after the user clicked the OK-Button.
I have created member-variables for the Text-widgets and trying to get the user's input with getText() after the user has clicked the OK-Button (and therefore has closed the dialog).

Unfortunately the widgets are disposed when the dialog closes (so, with clicking the OK-Button), and there is no way to call getText() on the Text-Widgets anymore.

I was wondering how others solve this use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply extend `Dialog.okPressed()` in your code to retrieve the current values before the dialogis closed...

Answer (score 1):

Use a datamodel, e.g. simple Pojos to store user-inputs. This model is bound via the Eclipse Databinding to your Ui, e.g. to a Textfield and is synchronized every time the user modifies the value of the textfield. Take a look at the tutorial how to integrate databinding in your application, see http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html

Comment: This seems like a bit of overkill for my use-case - i am querying just 2 strings from the user, which i want retrieve from the FormDialog.